# Limit AutoCompleteTextView to only one result

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using AutoCompleteTextView with a custom layout for the adapter. The problem is I don't know how to limit the results for only one at time, like in the default Layout.
I read that It's possible limiting the height, but doesn't work in all screens. Thanks for your attention.

I've this on my activity_main layout.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autotext" 
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="480dp" 
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:maxLength="23" 
android:maxLines="1" 
android:textColor="#000000" />
```

And this is the adapter's layout.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textpop" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

Comment: Do you use a custom adapter?

Comment: I don't use a custom adapter exactly, actually I use a custom layout on the ArrayAdapter, that only has the textview that appears in the code of the ask.

Comment: I'm guessing that by *limit the results for only one at time* you mean showing only one suggestion no matter how many fulfill the auto complete text. If this is the case you could implement your own adapter which only shows only one suggestion no matter what.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my explication, It was just I want to say. So I'll have to build an adaptor. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this code](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/dp/adapter/FilterWithSpaceAdapter.java). It's basically the code for the SDK `ArrayAdapter` class with a small modification(which doesn't count). If you want to show only one suggestion in the `AutoCompleteTextView` then you could make a small modification to the class from the link, to the `performFiltering()` method like this:

```
// ... the rest of that method
if (newValues.size() > 1) { // if we have more than an item in the list
    // get the first suggestion
    T oneItem = newValues.get(0);
    // empty the suggestion list
    newValues.clear();
    // add the only suggestion.
    newValues.add(oneItem);
}
results.values = newValues;
results.count = newValues.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the above answer unsatisfactory, and the link is dead.

For the simplest way to do this, create a custom adapter and simply force the count to 1

```
class SingleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public SingleArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own AutoCompleteTextView adapter which implement Filterable interface, or extend existing adapter, but override getFilter() method, create your own filter implementation, then you can customize filter logic and return any number of results you like.

You can refer to the ArrayFilter implementation in ArrayAdpater for reference.